# Loop through and modify list elements

Tags: r

I am trying to modify a named element in a list of lists like so:

```
A <- list(list(a=1,b=1),list(a=2,b=2))
A[[1]]$a == 1
```

Try to modify the elements:

```
for(e in A) e$a <- 10
```

Why does this still hold true?

```
A[[1]]$a == 1
```

And not this:

```
A[[1]]$a == 10
```

Also, what would be the suggested approach to actually assign `10` to each `.$a` element?

Comment: You have the 'a' element as 1 and not as 10.  The `for(e in A)` is not correct

Comment: Maybe `for(e in 1:length(A)) { A[[e]]$a <- 10 }` ?

Comment: Or you can impress your friends and do `lapply(A, "[[<-", "a", 10)`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Variables in R are always values, not references (though rarely, some packages may call other languages which produce referenced objects).

The temporary iterator value created by `for` is not a reference to the original values being iterated. Instead, it is an independent copy. So the code below:

```
for (e in A) {
    e$a <- 10
}
```

Will not work, because the temporary variable `e` is a new, independent copy of an element of `A`, not a reference to the corresponding element in `A`. Since `e` only exists within the scope of the `for` loop, this code has no effect on the larger script.

A quick way to accomplish what you want would be:

```
for (i in 1:length(A)) {
    A[[i]]$a <- 10
}
```

Comment: I went with seq_along